# How to Add Buttons to Notification Tray in GNOME using Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnome

I want to add buttons to a notification in GNOME using python. The Pic below shows what I want to Achieve (Top Notification), and what I can currently do (Bottom Notification)

[image]

Currently I can make buttons appear on the notification, but it does not show in the notification tray. Here is my code which makes that work:

```
import sys
from gi.repository import Notify, Gtk, GLib, Pango
from subprocess import call

def callback():
    pass

Notify.init("test")
n=Notify.Notification.new("test", "subtext")

n.add_action('prev', 'Previous', callback, None)
n.add_action('pause', 'Pause', callback, None)
n.add_action('next', 'Next', callback, None)

# n.set_timeout(0)
n.show()
```

How can I make my notification look more like the one above mine?

Comment: you should set an event loop ...call Gtk.main() at the end to see what happens

Comment: @user1438644, gives me the same result, other than the script not terminating after.